# Find adjacent regions in Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, region, regions

I would like to select all regions with value above 1 if they are connected to an element with value above 5.
Two values are not connected if they are separated by a 0.

For the following data set,

```
pd.Series(data = [0,2,0,2,3,6,3,0])
```

the output should be

```
pd.Series(data = [False,False,False,True,True,True,True,False])
```

Comment: The second 2 is not adjacent to a value  above 5. Can you clarify the definition.

Comment: Did this clarify?

Comment: is strictly above 1 or >=1?

Comment: This is a simplified example. I reality, I use floats, so it does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like I have found a one-liner, using pandas groupby function:

```
import pandas as pd

ts = pd.Series(data = [0,2,0,2,3,6,3,0])

# The flag column allows me to identify sequences. Here 0s are included 
# in the "sequence", but as you can see in next line doesn't matter 
df = pd.concat([ts, (ts==0).cumsum()], axis = 1, keys = ['val', 'flag'])

#   val  flag
#0    0     1
#1    2     1
#2    0     2
#3    2     2
#4    3     2
#5    6     2
#6    3     2
#7    0     3

# For each group (having the same flag), I do a boolean AND of two conditions:
# any value above 5  AND value above 1  (which excludes zeros) 
df.groupby('flag').transform(lambda x: (x>5).any() * x > 1)

#Out[32]: 
#     val
#0  False
#1  False
#2  False
#3   True
#4   True
#5   True
#6   True
#7  False
```

If you are wondering, you can collapse everything in one line:

```
ts.groupby((ts==0).cumsum()).transform(lambda x: (x>5).any() * x > 1).astype(bool)
```

I still leave for reference my first approach:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

def flatten(l):
    # Util function to flatten a list of lists
    # e.g. [[1], [2,3]] -> [1,2,3]
    return list(itertools.chain(*l))

ts = pd.Series(data = [0,2,0,2,3,6,3,0])
#Get data as list
values = ts.values.tolist()

# From what I understand the 0s delimit subsequences (so numbers are not
# connected if separated by a 0

# Get location of zeros
gap_loc = [idx for (idx, el) in enumerate(values) if el==0]  
# Re-create pandas series
gap_series = pd.Series(False, index = gap_loc)

# Get values and locations of the subsequences (i.e. seperated by zeros)
valid_loc = [range(prev_gap+1,gap) for prev_gap, gap in zip(gap_loc[:-1],gap_loc[1:])]
list_seq = [values[prev_gap+1:gap] for prev_gap, gap in zip(gap_loc[:-1],gap_loc[1:])]
# list_seq = [[2], [2, 3, 6, 3]]

# Verify your condition
check_condition = [[el>1 and any(map(lambda x: x>5, sublist)) for el in sublist] 
                     for sublist in list_seq]
# Put results back into a pandas Series
valid_series = pd.Series(flatten(check_condition), index = flatten(valid_loc))

# Put everything together:
result = pd.concat([gap_series, valid_series], axis = 0).sort_index()

#result
#Out[101]: 
#0    False
#1    False
#2    False
#3     True
#4     True
#5     True
#6     True
#7    False
#dtype: bool
```

Comment: You might want to check the new one liner solution

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself in an ugly way, see below. However, I would still like to know if there is a better way to do this.

```
test_series = pd.Series(data = [0,2,0,2,3,6,3,0])

bool_df = pd.DataFrame(data= [(test_series>1), (test_series>5)]).T 
bool_df.loc[:,0] = (bool_df.loc[:,0])&(~bool_df.loc[:,1])
# make a boolean DataFrame.
# Column 0 is values between 1 and 5, and column 1 is values above 5.
# the resulting boolean series we are looking for is column 1 after it has been modified in the following way.



k=0 # k is an integer that indexes the bool_df values that are less than 1
while k < len(bool_df.loc[bool_df.loc[:,0],0]):
    i = bool_df.loc[bool_df.loc[:,0],0].index[k] # the bool_df index corresponding to k
    if i > 0: # avoid negative indeces
        if bool_df.loc[i-1,1]: # Check if the previous entry had a value above 5
            bool_df.loc[i,1] = True
            k+=1
        else: 
            j=i
            while bool_df.loc[j,0]: # find the end of the streak of 1<values<5.
                j+=1
            bool_df.loc[i:j,1] = bool_df.loc[j,1] # set the whole streak to the value found at the end, either >5 or <1
            k = sum(bool_df.loc[bool_df.loc[:,0],0].index<j) 
    else:
        k+=1
```